# How to get multiple values with chrome.storage function?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension that allows you to browse the internet and save the domain and url that you visit.

Thanks to this script (in my popup.js file) I can store the data.

```
  chrome.storage.sync.set({keyDominio:keyDominio, keyUrl:keyUrl}, function() {

  });
```

The problem I have is when it comes to recovering them. I only manage to retrieve the last added data. My function to catch the stored data is:

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // ...query for the active tab...
  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {
      var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
  });
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['keyDominio', 'keyUrl'], function(result) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('addDomain')[i].textContent = result.keyDominio;
        document.getElementsByClassName('addUrl')[i].textContent = result.keyUrl;

    });

...});
```

How can I access the different saved values, not only the last one to be able to insert them into a table?

Comment: A key is unique and it stores just one value. The value can be an array, see the linked topic for an example.

Comment: Not working for me. Maybe because my storagekey is not an Array, is a Class. Can I do it with a Class? How? Or you think it will be better if I use an Array?

Comment: A key is always a string, it's neither a Class nor an Array. Currently the keys you're using are 'keyDominio' and 'keyUrl'. The linked topic shows how to store an array. You can use a key like 'data', and its value will be an array like [{domain: 'foo', url: 'bar'}, {domain: 'foo', url: 'bar'}, {domain: 'foo', url: 'bar'}]